# How to stop auto invoice generation with Credit Card or Paypal payment methods

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice

I need to stop Magento (version 1.8.1.0) from generating invoices automatically with credit card or paypal payment methods.

I look at registerCaptureNotification() in app/code/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php. If I comment out the following code snippet:

```
if (!$invoice) {
        if ($this->_isCaptureFinal($amount)) {
            // comment out the following to stop creating invoices automatically
            //$invoice = $order->prepareInvoice()->register();
            //$order->addRelatedObject($invoice);
            //$this->setCreatedInvoice($invoice);
        } else {
            if (!$skipFraudDetection) {
                $this->setIsFraudDetected(true);
            }
            $this->_updateTotals(array('base_amount_paid_online' => $amount));
        }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Invoices are still being generated using credit card payment.

What is the right way to prevent auto invoice generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karl,goto
**app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php**
copy to

**app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php**

here magento create invoice on paypal order

find the code:

**app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php**  goto function

here create invoice by below code:

```
if ($invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice()) {
            $message = Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getIncrementId());
            $comment = $order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment($message)
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                ->save();
        }
```

just change it to

```
$order->sendNewOrderEmail()
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                ->save();
```

here function  `$payment->getCreatedInvoice()` create `invoice of an order`

or used the extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/disable-automatic-generation-of-invoice.html

Comment: thanks... but that extension doesn't work with Magento 1.8.1.0 and it doesn't work with Credit Card (WorldPay).

Comment: every payment gate have different different logic.. their magento extension have customization  according to there logic. so, it not possible to define ,there we stop to create invoice.

Comment: I had some other problem on similar lines, but taking cue from this answer I could solve it. Thank you. Upvoted