# Disable auto invoice paypal express checkout

Tags: invoice, paypal-express

I Need to stop automatic invoices with PayPal express checkout. I just edited files:

```
app/code/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php
```

and

```
app/code/core/Mage/PayPal/Model/Ipn.php
```

but problem persist.

**When a customer create a new order and the payment is captured**, the order status change in `ORDER` and `INVOICED`, but I need to create invoice only after shipping.

I also tested extension "**Disable automatic generation of invoice**" but the issue remains.

Can I disable auto invoice with PayPal Express Checkout? My version is 1.8.1 and with standard PayPal there is no problem.

Thank you

Comment: so you have tried this? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/how-to-stop-auto-invoice-generation-with-credit-card-or-paypal-payment-methods

Comment: I just visit this post but problem persist

Comment: try this commenting out the following 

/* 
// notify customer 
if ($invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice()) { 
$comment = $this->_order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment( 
Mage::helper(’paypal’)->__(’Notified customer about invoice #%s.’, $invoice->getIncrementId()) 
) 
->setIsCustomerNotified(true) 
->save(); 
} 
*/

---

in: app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php (approx line 384)

Comment: i tried this but auto invoice not disabled