# auto invoice in magento 1.9.2 using paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, invoice

we need to disable the auto invoice created by magento after a paypal payment. The magento version is 1.9.2 and no settings are present to avoid this. Is there any paypal account setting to stop the auto invoice in magento 1.9.2 ?

Comment: Have you tried?
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/how-to-stop-auto-invoice-generation-with-credit-card-or-paypal-payment-methods

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the classical fix (the one [Raphael](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2380/raphael-at-digital-pianism) has pointed), and depending by the PayPal solution you are using, you'd take a look at **Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment** class, and modify some code according to your needs

Take a look at `capture()` & `registerCaptureNotification()` methods