# How to disable Paypal auto inovice generator in Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, invoice

I need to disable the generating of invoices when the payment method is PayPal.

I already tried this solution, but it doesn't work on Magento 1.9:
[How to stop auto invoice generation with Credit Card or Paypal payment methods](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/how-to-stop-auto-invoice-generation-with-credit-card-or-paypal-payment-methods)