# Magento 1.9.3.1 Stop auto invoicing of paypal orders

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, invoice, paypal-standard

I am using magento CE 1.9.3.1 and I would like to disable auto invoicing of orders placed by paypal. Tax point purposes I would like to invoice them manually in the magento backend myself like I do for the Purchase order orders.

Doing some research (Googling!) I found this:

[stop auto-invoice of paypal orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/how-to-stop-auto-invoice-generation-with-credit-card-or-paypal-payment-methods)

Now, this is nearly three years old from 2014 so is this still a viable solution for 1.9.3.1 ?

Or is there a more reliable solution ?

**Update**

I went and amended the registerCaptureNotification function in payment.php from prasantas answser below to the following:

```
 $status = true;
$letsEmail = false;
if ($this->getIsTransactionPending()) {
    $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capturing amount of %s is pending approval on gateway.', $this->_formatPrice($amount));
    $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;
    $letsEmail = true;
    if ($this->getIsFraudDetected()) {
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order is suspended as its capture amount %s is suspected to be fraudulent.', $this->_formatPrice($amount, $this->getCurrencyCode()));
        $status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATUS_FRAUD;
        $letsEmail = false;
    }
} else {
    $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Registered notification about captured amount of %s.', $this->_formatPrice($amount));
    $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW;
    $letsEmail = true;
    if ($this->getIsFraudDetected()) {
        $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order is suspended as its capture amount %s is suspected to be fraudulent.', $this->_formatPrice($amount, $this->getCurrencyCode()));
        $status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATUS_FRAUD;
        $letsEmail = false;
    }
}

$transaction = $this->_addTransaction(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE, $invoice, true);
$message = $this->_prependMessage($message);
$message = $this->_appendTransactionToMessage($transaction, $message);
$order->setState($state, $status, $message);
if ($letsEmail === true && !$order->getEmailSent()){
     $order->queueNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Notified Customer')
        )
        ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
        ->save();
}
```

This is now sending order confirmation emails.

**Update 2**

I now have an order where customer paid via paypal and then it showed pending-payment, which changed to cancelled and back to pending.

I cannot cancel the order, ship, invoice or nothing. only options we have are to edit,hold or delete order.

**Update 3**

I have also noticed that **paypal orders at random get cancelled**.

Below is a screenshot of an orders status history and as it illustrates an order goes to pending payment first then to pending. From here **3 seconds later** it is set to cancelled. **Why is this ?**

I enabled debug but nothing at all was recorded in the /var/log location. Looking at transaction history and and ipn history on paypal I can see that the payment has come through successfully and ipn was confirmed/completed.

[image: Order being cancelled]

> I would now just like to know why sporadically (1 in 4 or so) the
>   paypal orders get cancelled even though paypal order was successfully
>   placed and paid for and payment information passed back to magento?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop auto invoice generation with Credit Card or Paypal payment methods](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/how-to-stop-auto-invoice-generation-with-credit-card-or-paypal-payment-methods)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara that is referring credit card payments mainly and also an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice.xml in app/etc/modules/ and put the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice>
</modules>
</config>
```

Create a file config.xml in app/code/local/Wfh/DisableAutoInvoice/etc/ and put the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <disableautoinvoice>
            <class>Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>disableautoinvoice_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </disableautoinvoice>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
        <order_payment>Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice_Model_Sales_Order_Payment</order_payment>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

Create a file Payment.php in app/code/local/Wfh/DisableAutoInvoice/Model/Sales/Order/ and put the following code.

```
class Wfh_DisableAutoInvoice_Model_Sales_Order_Payment extends     Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment
{   

/**
 * Authorize or authorize and capture payment on gateway, if applicable
 * This method is supposed to be called only when order is placed
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment
 */
public function place()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_payment_place_start', array('payment' => $this));
    $order = $this->getOrder();

    $this->setAmountOrdered($order->getTotalDue());
    $this->setBaseAmountOrdered($order->getBaseTotalDue());
    $this->setShippingAmount($order->getShippingAmount());
    $this->setBaseShippingAmount($order->getBaseShippingAmount());

    $methodInstance = $this->getMethodInstance();
    $methodInstance->setStore($order->getStoreId());
    $orderState = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW;
    $stateObject = new Varien_Object();

    /**
     * Do order payment validation on payment method level
     */
    $methodInstance->validate();
    $action = $methodInstance->getConfigPaymentAction();
    if ($action) {
        if ($methodInstance->isInitializeNeeded()) {
            /**
             * For method initialization we have to use original config value for payment action
             */
            $methodInstance->initialize($methodInstance->getConfigData('payment_action'), $stateObject);
        } else {
            $orderState = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW;
            switch ($action) {
                case Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::ACTION_ORDER:
                    $this->_order($order->getBaseTotalDue());
                    break;
                case Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::ACTION_AUTHORIZE:
                    $this->_authorize(true, $order->getBaseTotalDue()); // base amount will be set inside
                    $this->setAmountAuthorized($order->getTotalDue());
                    break;
                case Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::ACTION_AUTHORIZE_CAPTURE:
                    $this->setAmountAuthorized($order->getTotalDue());
                    $this->setBaseAmountAuthorized($order->getBaseTotalDue());
                    $this->capture(null);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->_createBillingAgreement();

    $orderIsNotified = null;
    if ($stateObject->getState() && $stateObject->getStatus()) {
        $orderState      = $stateObject->getState();
        $orderStatus     = $stateObject->getStatus();
        $orderIsNotified = $stateObject->getIsNotified();
    } else {
        $orderStatus = $methodInstance->getConfigData('order_status');
        if (!$orderStatus) {
            $orderStatus = $order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($orderState);
        } else {
            // check if $orderStatus has assigned a state
            $states = $order->getConfig()->getStatusStates($orderStatus);
            if (count($states) == 0) {
                $orderStatus = $order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($orderState);
            }
        }
    }
    $isCustomerNotified = (null !== $orderIsNotified) ? $orderIsNotified : $order->getCustomerNoteNotify();

    $message = $order->getCustomerNote();
    // add message if order was put into review during authorization or capture
    if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW) {
        if ($message) {
            $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $message, $isCustomerNotified);
        }
    } elseif ($order->getState() && ($orderStatus !== $order->getStatus() || $message)) {
        // add message to history if order state already declared
        $order->setState($orderState, $orderStatus, $message, $isCustomerNotified);
    } elseif (($order->getState() != $orderState) || ($order->getStatus() != $orderStatus) || $message) {
        // set order state
        $order->setState($orderState, $orderStatus, $message, $isCustomerNotified);
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_payment_place_end', array('payment' => $this));

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Capture the payment online
 * Does not create invoice automatically for order
 * Updates transactions hierarchy, if required
 * Updates payment totals, updates order status and adds proper comments
 *
 * TODO: eliminate logic duplication with registerCaptureNotification()
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
public function capture($invoice)
{

    $invoice = null;
    $order = $this->getOrder();

    $amountToCapture = $this->_formatAmount($order->getBaseGrandTotal());

    $paidWorkaround = (float)$amountToCapture;
    $this->_isCaptureFinal($paidWorkaround);

    $this->_generateTransactionId(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE,
        $this->getAuthorizationTransaction()
    );

    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_payment_capture', array('payment' => $this, 'invoice' => $invoice));

    $status = true;
    if (!$this->getIsTransactionPending()) {
        // attempt to capture: this can trigger "is_transaction_pending"
        $this->getMethodInstance()->setStore($order->getStoreId())->capture($this, $amountToCapture);

        $transaction = $this->_addTransaction(
            Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE,
            $invoice,
            true
        );

        if ($this->getIsTransactionPending()) {
            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capturing amount of %s is pending approval on gateway.', $this->_formatPrice($amountToCapture));
            $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;
            if ($this->getIsFraudDetected()) {
                $status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATUS_FRAUD;
            }
        } else { // normal online capture: invoice is marked as "paid"
            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Captured amount of %s online.', $this->_formatPrice($amountToCapture));
            $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW;
            $this->_updateTotals(array('base_amount_paid_online' => $amountToCapture));
        }
        if ($order->isNominal()) {
            $message = $this->_prependMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Nominal order registered.'));
        } else {
            $message = $this->_prependMessage($message);
            $message = $this->_appendTransactionToMessage($transaction, $message);
        }
        $order->setState($state, $status, $message);

        return $this;
    }
    Mage::throwException(
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('The transaction "%s" cannot be captured yet.', $amountToCapture)
    );
}

/**
 * Process a capture notification from a payment gateway for specified amount
 * Does not create an invoice automatically if the amount if the amount covers the order base grand total completely
 * Updates transactions hierarchy, if required
 * Prevents transaction double processing
 * Updates payment totals, updates order status and adds proper comments
 *
 * TODO: eliminate logic duplication with capture()
 *
 * @param float $amount
 * @param bool $skipFraudDetection
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment
 */
public function registerCaptureNotification($amount, $skipFraudDetection = false)
{

    $this->_generateTransactionId(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE,
        $this->getAuthorizationTransaction()
    );

    $order   = $this->getOrder();
    $amount  = (float)$amount;
    $invoice = null;

    // register new capture
    if (!$invoice) {
        $isSameCurrency = $this->_isSameCurrency();
        if (!$isSameCurrency && !$this->_isCaptureFinal($amount)) {
            if (!$skipFraudDetection || !$isSameCurrency) {
                $this->setIsFraudDetected(true);
            }
            $this->_updateTotals(array('base_amount_paid_online' => $amount));
        }
    }

    $status = true;
    if ($this->getIsTransactionPending()) {
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capturing amount of %s is pending approval on gateway.', $this->_formatPrice($amount));
        $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;
        if ($this->getIsFraudDetected()) {
            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order is suspended as its capture amount %s is suspected to be fraudulent.', $this->_formatPrice($amount, $this->getCurrencyCode()));
            $status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATUS_FRAUD;
        }
    } else {
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Registered notification about captured amount of %s.', $this->_formatPrice($amount));
        $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW;
        if ($this->getIsFraudDetected()) {
            $state = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;
            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order is suspended as its capture amount %s is suspected to be fraudulent.', $this->_formatPrice($amount, $this->getCurrencyCode()));
            $status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATUS_FRAUD;
        }
    }

    $transaction = $this->_addTransaction(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE, $invoice, true);
    $message = $this->_prependMessage($message);
    $message = $this->_appendTransactionToMessage($transaction, $message);
    $order->setState($state, $status, $message);
    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry how would I rewrite the that model ?

Comment: I have edited the answer please check

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite entire payment model ? I just need for paypal payments

Comment: You can restrict according to payment method by payment method code in order. ex :-   if( $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()!="payment_method_code_here"){
   return parent::place();
}

if( $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()!="payment_method_code_here"){
   return parent::capture($invoice);
}

if( $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()!="payment_method_code_here"){
   return parent::registerCaptureNotification($amount, $skipFraudDetection );
}

Comment: there should be some error coming. Check that.

Comment: sure, this will still work the same way for paypal orders other than auto invoice

Comment: Prasanta please see my updates above, this code is broken I believe and not working correctly.