# Change order status after order placed regardless payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, order-status

I am using **Magento ver. 1.9.2.3**.

I want the system to take the order as **“Order Pending”** status when any **orders over $1100.00** regardless any payment method.

Now when a user **pay with 'eway-Credit card'** or with **'PAYPAL'** then an invoice is generated and an email goes to customer with an invoice pdf as attachment. I also want to **prevent this invoice email going** to user in this  case **when order is over $1100.00**.

Comment: By default system takes status as pending while customer place an order in your first case. Then what is the problem in your first case ?

Comment: @ Ramkishan, Yes, that is true that it takes status as Pending by default but when user pays using credit card or paypal, it generates invoice and send invoice email, I don't want this email being processed and keep order status as pending.

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34231/45103